# PHP Warning: array_rand() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given

Tags: php, arrays, boolean

My code:

```
$input = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "8", "15", "22");
$value1=$input[array_rand($input)];
```

I want to randomize given numbers and get just one numbers of them back to "$input", but I got an error : 
"PHP Warning:  array_rand() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in...

Line where this error is triggered is here:

```
$value1=$input[array_rand($input)];
```

How to fix that error ?

?

Thanks!

Comment: ..because `$input`is of type boolean, not an array. [RTM](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php)

Comment: since we don't know what $input is, or where it comes from, we can't really help. Fact is, $input is not an array.

Comment: @Jeff Oh, that's great, thanks very much for that information, so what to do to not read this error on my server over and over again ?

Comment: Are you serious? Did you even read the error message? It could not be any clearer.

Comment: @Sverri M. Olsen I am sorry, but I have no idea what to do to fix that.

Comment: @Jeff Do that mean I have just to change '$input' to '$somethingelse' ??

Comment: @AzemHajdari What to do not to read the error? _FIX THE ERROR_. Show more code (where $input comes from) or Read the Manual.

Comment: @Jeff With "What to do?" I already mean "How to FIX?" More code: $input = array("1", "2", "3", "4, "5", "6");

Comment: Whatever you want to pass to array_rand() has to be an array (otherwise it doesn't make sense). Please Edit your question with the whole code. Even the oneline in comments is not enough.

Comment: @AzemHajdari turn on error reporting / show all errors in your development environment. You have a syntax error in the code you pasted for setting the $input variable

Comment: @JimL syntax error here in this line? $input = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "8", "15", "22");

Comment: OKAY: Now I am EDITED my question, because it seems you want all tell me WHY I am get that error and nobody provide me any solution HOW to FIX error, so now it does NOT interested me WHY but HOW TO FIX it? Thank you all, specialists. ;-)

Comment: Not the right moment to be pissed off. We're trying to help, and we got a bit of experience in that. Finding out WHY you get the error is the only way to FIX the error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
$input = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "8", "15", "22"];

$randomInputIndex = rand(0, count($input)); // Returns any integer between 0 and 8 in your case
$randomInputValue = $input[$randomInputIndex];
// $input[0] returns 1
// $input[1] returns 2
// $input[7] returns 15
// $input[8] returns 22
```

Or simply use:

```
$input = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "8", "15", "22"];

$randomInputValue = array_rand($input);
```

Read more about PHP's arrays [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Comment: I am think that something is like that, because if I remember correctly same types of "boolean" error I am getting when I edited my code from "mysql" to "mysqli"... I am sure that will work! Many thanks JasonK !

Comment: I need $input to be just 1 given RANDOM number from those : "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "8", "15", "22"

Comment: Both examples should do exactly that... have you tried them out already?

Comment: that second version will work for me I guess, There is not needed to count, but important is just to give me back randomly one number from those numbers given: "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "8", "15", "22" etc. Thank you so much mr. JasonK!

Comment: No problem, please accept the answer if it solved your problem. Good luck.

Comment: I've accepted JasonK, thank you a million times again! Best regards!

Answer (score 1):

Just the way you need it!

```
$input = array("preto", "vermelho", "laranja", "roxo", "abacate", "pera", "uva");


$random = array_rand($input, 1);
print_r($input[$random]);
```

Result random unique:

> laranja

Answer (score 0):

```
$value1= $input->random(number);
```

ps: number = number of element you want to get ,